# JBoss - how to run a deployed .war through web browser?

Tags: java, jboss, server, jboss7.x, war

I have deployed a .war file on my JAS 7 server, but when I go to http://localhost:8080/warfile, it gives me a 404 error.

Do I have to configure the web.xml somehow so that when I go to this URL, it launches my application?

Comment: What kind of application is it?  Servlet?

Comment: it's just a gui program that i have converted into a WAR. I would like to run it as something of a servlet but i didn't make that specification in the code itself.

Comment: Just packaging an application into a WAR file doesn't make it a web application.

Comment: oh. how do I go about turning it into something that can be run on my JBoss server then? It works fine when I run it as a dynamic web project in Eclipse

Comment: It depends much on what you want it to do.  If you want to just display your existing GUI application from a web browser, you're probably not looking for a web application at all, but an applet instead.  What kind of GUI is it?  Swing?

Comment: yeah it is using Swing. basically the program requests info from a database on my network and then analyzes some data and spits out some excel files. all I really want to do is run it as it is but from a jboss server, so that I can run it on separate computers on my network.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a web application, and it would take a significant amount of rewriting to make it one.  I would suggest packaging this as an `Applet`, more specifically as a `JApplet`.  Please refer to

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html

JBoss is not required to deploy an applet.  All that is necessary is a web server and an HTML wrapper.

Comment: could i set up my own machine to be a web server and an HTML wrapper ?

Comment: also, would converting my program into a servlet be a viable alternative?

Comment: An HTML wrapper is a file.  Just a regular text file.  Just install Apache, and you have a web server.

Comment: As for converting you application into a servlet, it would indeed be a viable alternative, but it would require some rewriting.

Comment: i've been reading about java web start. would it be possible to simply create a java web start for my program and then host it on my jboss server?

Comment: Sure, that will work.  If memory serves, Java Web Start works a lot like an applet.  But, even then a JBoss server is overkill.  Just a web server is required.

Answer (score 0):

Just a checklist

- Are you sure Jboss is running in port 8080?
- The  the **warfile** used by Jboss is the one declared in jboss-web.xml (under /WEB-INF folder), should look something like this:

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
<context-root>/yourAppName</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```